# RGoogleDocs Token Invalid Error

Tags: r

I have a confidential spreadsheet I'd like to access via the `RGoogleDocs` library but am receiving an odd error. This same code worked yesterday in order to fetch the worksheet. It was failing on the `sheetsAsMatrix` call. Now I can't even fetch the worksheet at all.  `options(error=recover)` doesn't tell me anything outside of the invalid token error message.

```
auth = getGoogleAuth("email@email.com", "password")
sheets.con = getGoogleDocsConnection(auth, service = "wise")

docs = getDocs(sheets.con)
names(docs)
 [1] "Testing Plan 0.1"                    
 [2] "All Events Template 11 1 13"

ts = getWorksheets("All Events Template 11 1 13", sheets.con)

Error in getDocs(con, what = "spreadsheets") : 
   problems connecting to get the list of documents: Token invalid (401)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to my own problem in case anyone else needs a workaround as well, I ended up using googlecl (https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) and just executed a `system` call in R to download the spreadsheet I needed. Finally I read it into R using the `XLConnect` library.